# Preguntando, que es gerundio

Tags: modismos, coloquialismos, gerundio

Podemos encontrar esta coletilla en algunos [textos](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22que%20es%20gerundio%22), aunque sospecho que es más frecuente en el habla popular.

Cuando se emplea, suele ser acompañando a un gerundio que actúa a modo de orden, como en: *¡Acabando, que es gerundio! ¡No quiero llegar tarde por vuestra culpa!*; o en: *—¿Está todo listo? —Sí. —Pues saliendo, que es gerundio.*

Mi pregunta es: más allá de la tautología implícita, **¿por qué a veces añadimos *"que es gerundio"*? ¿Cuál es la función de esta coletilla, y desde cuándo se usa?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Significado

«*... que es gerundio*» funciona como un exhortativo, siguiendo un gerundio para implicar que es un imperativo (como en tus ejemplos), aunque a veces se usa con su propio significado exhortativo:

> ### Andando/<sub>arreando</sub>, que es gerundio
>
> Y claro que es gerundio, ¿pero por qué se lo recordamos a una persona cuando queremos decirle que hay que irse de un lugar o comenzar a hacer algo? *Son ya las doce, así que, andando, que es gerundio, que mañana hay que levantarse pronto.* Para explicar el origen del dicho se cuenta el chascarrillo del campesino que mandó a su hijo, más bien corto de entendederas, a estudiar a Salamanca, pero el pobre muchacho apenas co-gió un leve barniz de ciencia en su estancia en el estudio salmantino. Un día su padre le ordenó que sacara al burro del establo y lo llevara al campo. Tal vez intentando sacarle alguna utilidad práctica a lo aprendido, cuentan que conducía al animal por las calles del pueblo al grito de: «Arreando, que es gerundio». No está mal recordar aquí que el excesivo uso del gerundio no es nada recomendable pues, aparte de llevarnos a cometer considerables errores gramaticales y de ser causa de ambigüedades («Vi a Luis entrando en el banco». ¿Quién entraba?), lleva con frecuencia a la afectación y a la cursilería; no en vano, el padre José Francisco de Isla (1703-1781) llamó Fray Gerundio a su ridículo predicador, modelo de los que mucho hablan y nada dicen, protagonista de su novela *Historia del famoso predicador Fray Gerundio de Campazas, alias Zotes*. **Por cierto, tan unida está esta coletilla gramatical a la orden de ponerse en marcha que a veces se dice todo uno, como si la palabra *gerundio* también significara *salir* o *marcharse*** y se oyen curiosidades como *nos vamos, que es gerundio*.
>
> - [*Diccionario de dichos y frases hechas*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UV23VTQe4PQC&q=%22que%20es%20gerundio%22)

> Pero ocurre, además, que se produce de hecho aprovechamiento "literal" del cliché (paremiológico o no) incluso en ciertas ocasiones en que el hablante, urgido por la inmediatez coloquial, extiende analógicamente su empleo a un contexto verbal poco acorde con el que suele ser asociado:
>
> - Bueno, al trabajo, *que es gerundio* [cp. "andando, que es gerundio"]
>
> [*Pre-texto y realización del sentido en el español coloquial*](https://cvc.cervantes.es/Lengua/paremia/pdf/002/037_vigara.pdf), Vigara Tauste (1993)

## ¿Desde cuando se usa?

Aparece primero en la palabra escrita en los años 30:

> [...] que se me guise por una sola cocina: la española, y que no se me fría la sangre en ningún idioma. entendiendo (que es gerundio): que caso de que los señores Herederos no cumplan alguna...
>
> - [*Pero... ¿hubo alguna vez once mil vírgenes?*](http://corpus.rae.es/cgi-bin/crpsrvEx.dll?visualizar?tipo1=5&tipo2=0&iniItem=1&ordenar1=0&ordenar2=0&FID=270319%5C009%5CC000O27032019093627461.1020.1016&desc=%7BB%7D+%7BI%7D+que+es+gerundio%7B|I%7D,+en+todos+los+medios,+en+%7BI%7DCORDE+%7B|I%7D+%7B|B%7D%7BBR%7D&tamVen=1&marcas=0#acierto1) (1931)

> **Rosita.** ¡Pirando, que es gerundio!
>
> - [*El debut de la patro: sainete de costumbres madrileñas, en dos actos,*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ku4PAQAAIAAJ&q="que+es+gerundio"&dq="que+es+gerundio") (1933)

> C. — (*Aprovechando, que es gerundio.*) ¡ A propósito! Bien podías llevarme una noche a ver una lucha en el Circo.
>
> - [*Blanco y Negro*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EugcMZOjSmUC&q="que+es+gerundio"), Vol. 46 (1936)

Answer (score 3):

No encuentro ninguna fuente que lo confirme "oficialmente" pero parece que viene de una historia o chascarrillo que se contaba que decía así:

> Se dice que unos campesinos enviaron a su hijo a estudiar a Salamanca.
>   El chico no era muy listo pero aprovechó lo que pudo. Una vez de
>   vuelta su padre le pidió que llevase al burro de un lugar a otro, y el
>   mozo, para demostrar cuánto había aprendido, iba gritando al pobre
>   asno *arreando, que es gerundio*, para regocijo de cuántos le oían.

---

Varios enlaces donde se cuenta esta historia:

<sub>https://losandes.com.ar/article/view?slug=andando-que-es-gerundio-por-maria-del-rosario-ramallo</sub>
   <sub>http://www.1de3.es/2006/09/15/arreando-que-es-gerundio/</sub>  
  <sub>https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/arreando,_que_es_gerundio</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Por afinar un poco [la respuesta de ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/28955/12637), en la hemeroteca de la BNE los primeros resultados aparecen en 1927, y además dos ese año sin que hubiera nada previo, así que debió de ser una invención poco anterior a ese año. Os dejo con los primeros ejemplos:

> [Título de una sección:] Azorineando, que es gerundio.
>
> **El Liberal (Madrid).** 29/1/1927, página 2.
>
> ---
>
> —Agradeciendo, que es gerundio.
>   —Gerundio, sí, señor. Veo que está usted bien de gramática.
>
> **El Heraldo de Madrid.** 23/4/1927, página 9.
>
> ---
>
> Blanquita Pozas, como siempre, enajenadora y enajenable de puro guapa.
>   Peña, Heredia y Lledó rivalizando —que es gerundio— en gracia de
>   facultades.
>
> **El Heraldo de Madrid.** 5/12/1928, página 6.

El hecho de que los tres ejemplos sean de Madrid nos da una pista del lugar donde se creó la expresión, además de la aproximación temporal.